# NoClassDefFoundError when I want to dockerize my SpringWebFlux project

Tags: spring, docker, gradle, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to dockerize my reactive SpringBootApp.

This is main class: [Main Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa1l7.png)

But I got this Error: [**NoClassDefFoundError**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlcYk.png)

Here is my build.gradle file:

[Build.gradle Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLvfl.png)

[Build.gradle Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z905.png)

Here is my Dockerfile: [DockerFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv7AZ.png)

Can someone suggest me, how can I resolve this problem?

Also, I'm using PostgreSQL in my app. Should I add something for docker to work, or nothing is needed?

Here is my PostgreSQL Configuration: [PostgreSQL Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhyoI.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, configuration, or other text / files. Copy the original text here + possibly format with the code format tool.

Comment: Ok, I will do it like that for the next time, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on gradle but I think you are missing dependency
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'

for more info check this:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_spring_boot_web_applications.html

Comment: It's reactive application, so I use:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux' 
instead of your suggestion: 
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'. 

My app works when I run it with IntelliJ and not with docker

Comment: can you run the app with command line? java -jar  app.jar ?

Comment: Same error... NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: But I can run the app with java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
This demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is in build/libs folder and app.jar is in build/docker folder.

Comment: When I run with docker demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar creates in build/libs folder and it is the same as app.jar, because in my docker configuration I'm renaming it to app.jar. But this demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar is different from demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. Why are they different?

Comment: my guess is that demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar has only your app files without dependencies , you can unzip it to explore. So your docker  ${jar_file} shall point to demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar not *plain one

Comment: Yes, in demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar there are only app files without libraries and etc. but I could not understand how to change pointer to demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Comment: as a hack you can use absolute path to JAR in you docker file.
But I encourage you to learn all details of your environment and build process.